# How do I populate a row with data from another table?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have two tables, one with a column of strings and a column of string IDs, the other is empty, but it will hold photo IDs and string IDs. If it helps visualize things, they were created with these commands.

```
CREATE TABLE tag_ref (
  tag_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  tag_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE tag (
  tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  photo_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

The user is supplying a photo_id and a tag_name. I need to get the corresponding tag_id and add a row to the tag table. I've made a couple of attempts, but neither one worked.

Attempt #1 (Assuming that the user is supplying photo_id 402 and tag_name "nature")

```
SELECT tag_id
  FROM tag_ref
  JOIN tag ON tag.tag_id = tag_ref.tag_id;
INSERT INTO tag (photo_id,  tag_id)
  WHERE 'nature' = tag_ref.tag_name
  VALUES (402, tag_ref.tag_id);
```

> ERROR: pq: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Attempt #2

```
INSERT INTO tag (tag_id, photo_id)
  SELECT tag_id, tag_name
  FROM tag_ref
WHERE 'nature' = tag_ref.tag_name
VALUES (402, tag_ref.tag_id)
```

> ERROR: pq: syntax error at or near "VALUES"

I am still very new to relational databases, but I feel like this shouldn't be a difficult operation. Am I even coming close?

Comment: You can use a `SELECT` _or_ a `VALUES` clause with `INSERT` but not both. #2 is closer but even if you remove the `VALUES` it will fail because `tag_name` is text and can't go into the integer `photo_id` column. Postgres' [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) are extensive and full of examples for what you're trying to do. Also, please supply error messages as a general point since not all problems are as easily identifiable as bad SQL syntax.

Comment: I apologize. I've updated my question to include error messages. I have actually looked at that doc to find something that comes close to my needs. I was able to find - INSERT INTO tag SELECT tag_id FROM tag_ref WHERE 'nature' = tag_ref.tag_name; - Which is great for finding the tag id, but it leaves me nowhere to insert any other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this simple `select`:

```
select tag_id, 402 from tag_ref where tag_name = 'nature'
```

this gives tag id by `tag_name` and hard coded `photo_id` (402 in your case)

Then just do `insert into .. select`:

```
insert into tag
(tag_id, photo_id)
select tag_id, 402 from tag_ref where tag_name = 'nature'
```

Comment: Oh wow, that works perfectly. I had no idea you could supply inputs to SELECT like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looing for `INSERT INTO ... select`

```
  INSERT INTO tag (photo_id,  tag_id)
  SELECT 402,tag_ref.tag_id
  FROM tag_ref
  JOIN tag ON tag.tag_id = tag_ref.tag_id
  WHERE 'nature' = tag_ref.tag_name
```

**Note**

there are two column named `tag_id` in your query, one is from `tag_ref` another is from `tag` you need to tell DB engine `tag_id` which table did you want to get for this column .

Comment: Okay, I attempted to run this query and it didn't quite work. There was no error message. It doesn't look terribly different from Shavadze's answer though. Taking out the JOIN seems to make it work.